# How to .map() meta tag in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to .map the content of meta, but the mapping is replicate multiple times of whole meta tags. Here my code is.

```
{general.head.articleAuthor.en.map(( ) => (
          <meta property="article:author" content={general.head.articleAuthor.en} />
        ))}
```

```
export const general = {
head: {
articleAuthor: {
en: ['name1', 'name2']}
}
}
```

I'm expecting the output should be like this `<meta property="article:author" content="name1,name2"/>`

But my code is mapping as this `<meta property="article:author" content="name1,name2"/> <meta property="article:author" content="name1,name2"/>`

Now if I add `name3` then it's mapping the whole meta for 3 times. I don't want the meta tags to replicate. I need the content to map.

Comment: *"but the mapping is replicate multiple times of whole meta tags"* That seems to be what you're telling it to do. What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I just need the name1, name2 to map. Not the whole meta tags mapping multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

> ...but the mapping is replicate multiple times of whole meta tags...

I can think of two interpretations of that. But in a comment you've written:

> I just need the name1, name2 to map. Not the whole meta tags mapping multiple times.

It sounds like you want a *single* `meta` tag containing all of the authors. To do that, use `join` rather than `map`:

```
<meta property="article:author" content={general.head.articleAuthor.en.join(", ")} />
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That will give you

```
<meta property="article:author" content="name1, name2"} />
```

or similar. The string is the separator. So if you don't want a space after the comma, just change it from `", "` to `","`.

---

The other way I read the question, which I now think is incorrect but may be useful to others, is that you wanted a `meta` for each author. To do that, use the value passed to `map` rather than using `general.head.articleAuthor.en` in `content`:

```
{general.head.articleAuthor.en.map(author => (
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
  <meta property="article:author" content={author} />
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of all use the current obj in the iteration:

```
{general.head.articleAuthor.en.map((obj) => (
      <meta property="article:author" content={obj} />
 ))}
```

> *I'm expecting the output should be like this `<meta property="article:author" content="name1,name2"/>`*

As `en` is defined as an array so you can use `.join()` to get the all values in one meta tag. It doesn't need to map.

```
{ <meta property="article:author" content={general.head.articleAuthor.en.join(',')} /> }
```